# How to easily rename all the factors in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have renamed all the factor using revalue function from plyr package. However, I thought there might easier way to solve this problem.

```
cleandata <- Eyedata%>%
mutate(MediaName = revalue(MediaName, c("none_1-1.jpg" = "C11", 
"none_1-2.jpg" = "C12", "none_1-3.jpg" = "C13", 
"none_1-4.jpg" = "C14", "none_1-5.jpg" = "C15", 
"none_1-6.jpg" = "C16", "none_1-7.jpg" = "C17", 
"none_1-8.jpg" = "C18", "none_1-9.jpg" = "C19",
"none_2-1.jpg" = "C21", "none_2-2.jpg" = "C22", 
"none_2-3.jpg" = "C23", "none_2-4.jpg" = "C24",
"none_2-5.jpg" = "C25", "none_2-6.jpg" = "C26", 
"none_2-7.jpg" = "C27", "none_2-8.jpg" = "C28", 
"none_2-9.jpg" = "C29")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Benjamin Ye, you need a concatenation :

```
Eyedata %>% mutate(MediaName = paste0("C", str_extract(MediaName, "[0-9]+-[0-9]+")))) %>% mutate(MediaName = gsub("-", "", MediaName))
```

You can use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package to get the part of the string with numbers and delete the `-` with gsub

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct in my assumption, the `MediaName` column in your `Eyedata` `data.frame` or `tibble` currently has the values `"none_1-1.jpg", "none_1-2.jpg", ...`?

If that's the case, I noticed that the replacement values is simply a concatenation of `"C"` and the two numbers in the file names. Perhaps a more efficient way that uses less hardcoding would be something along the lines of `Eyedata %>% mutate(MediaName = paste0('C', gsub('\\D+', '', MediaName)))`, which will simply replace all instances of non-numerical digits with blanks and append `"C"` to the remaining digits. (If you already have `stringr` or `tidyverse` loaded, you can use `str_c()` instead.)

Comment: @BalachandarKaliappan Just letting you know that `gsub()` can match all non-numerical values and delete them in one go, which may be faster.

Comment: Thanks again. I am working on it. Because, I have two different variables for the MediaName - where one is none_1-1.jpg and the other is trans_1-1.jpg . I need to replace none with C and trans with D. Working on it now using gsub